# Java Scanner do-while Lack of Recognition Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, do-while

I have created a do-loop to continue iterating until the user enters a word starting with Y or N, originally using a primitive check on a *char* and now using the methods outlined below to check strings for equality. With both comparison media, I found that even with 'y' or 'n' entered, the loop would not exit. I cannot explain why, and hope that you can:

The following is the code:

```
            do{
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Valid y/n Reply:");
            eraseOr_no = histScanner.next();
            if(histScanner.hasNext()){
                (eraseOr_no.replaceAll("\\s+", "")).toLowerCase();
                character = Character.toString(eraseOr_no.charAt(0));

                //DEBUGGING
                System.out.println("CHECKPOINT 5" + "----" + character);
                //DEBUGGING

            }
        }while(!(character.equals("n")) || !(character.equals("y")));
```

As is clear I have used a simply system to inform me of the value of the *String* **character**, and as you may be able to see it is successfully displaying the 'y' or 'n' meaning that my first-letter-retrieval code is functioning, though the entire do structure is not.

```
Continue
Answer:

CHECKPOINT 4.0.
PLACEHOLDER

Please Enter a Valid y/n Reply:
y
y
CHECKPOINT 5----y
Please Enter a Valid y/n Reply:
y
CHECKPOINT 5----y
Please Enter a Valid y/n Reply:
n
CHECKPOINT 5----y
Please Enter a Valid y/n Reply:
y
CHECKPOINT 5----n
Please Enter a Valid y/n Reply:
```

Should I try to remove all whitespace? Am I missing something more fundamental?

Answer (score 2):

You're saying:

> while (character ***is not*** `n`) ***or*** (character ***is not*** `y`)

At least one of those conditions will always be true! If it's `n` then it's not `y`, and if it's `y` then it's not `n` (and if it's neither then *both* conditions are satisfied).

You probably want:

```
while (!(character.equals("n") || character.equals("y")))
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I will put this to good use.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong. It is either:

```
while(!(character.equals("n")) && !(character.equals("y"))); // A
```

or,

```
while(!(character.equals("n") || character.equals("y"))); // B
```

In words, this is, either:

> (not `"n"`) and (not `"y"`)          `//A`

or:

> neither `"n"` nor `"y"`        `//B`

Comment: DeMorgan's rules strike again!

Comment: Oh God I am so stupid. Thank you. I suppose then I am no logician. Case closed.

Comment: @chrylis: Nice, now I have a name to refer to in the future ;)